# How to use numpy and strides to improve performance of loop

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to numpy and just heard about strides, but I'm having trouble getting my head wrapped around how to use them. I have a small loop that is very slow and it seems like a good example that might work for strides.

```
def semivariogram( ds, band, lag ):
    width = ds.RasterXSize
    height = ds.RasterYSize
    data = band.ReadAsArray( 0, 0, width, height ).astype(np.float)
    #print 'w: {}, h: {}'.format(width, height)

    sumw = 0.0
    sumh = 0.0
    for i in range(width-lag):
        for j in range(height-lag):
            sumw += data[i+lag,j]-data[i,j]
            sumh += data[i,j+lag]-data[i,j]

    Nh2 = 2.0*(width-lag)*(height-lag)

    return [sumw/Nh2, sumh/Nh2, (sumw/Nh2+sumh/Nh2)/2.0]
```

The line:

```
data = band.ReadAsArray( 0, 0, width, height ).astype(np.float)
```

is reading one band of an image into an array of floats. And `ds` is a handle to an image like:

```
ds = gdal.Open('test.tif')
```

Comment: why are you sure you need numpy strides? Those correspond to the way the data is stired. The code you provided needs to be written using numpy vector and slicing operation to get benefit from using numpy.

Comment: Isn't your code just doing `sumw = data[lag:,:].sum() - data[:-lag,:].sum()`?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, let's do this step by step.

You have:

```
sumw = 0.0
sumh = 0.0
for i in range(width-lag):
    for j in range(height-lag):
        sumw += data[i+lag,j]-data[i,j]
        sumh += data[i,j+lag]-data[i,j]
```

Let's split this into two loops for clarity

```
sumw = 0.0
for i in range(width-lag):
    for j in range(height-lag):
        sumw += data[i+lag,j]-data[i,j]
sumh = 0.0
for j in range(height-lag):
    for i in range(width-lag):
        sumh += data[i,j+lag]-data[i,j]
```

We can write `data[i,j+lag]` as `data[:-lag,lag:][i,j]`, and `data[i,j]` is `data[:-lag,:-lag][i,j]` (for our range of `i` and `j`, and assuming lag != 0). So our loops become:

```
sumw = 0.0
for i in range(width-lag):
    for j in range(height-lag):
        sumw += data[lag:,:-lag][i,j]-data[:-lag,:-lag][i,j]
sumh = 0.0
for j in range(height-lag):
    for i in range(width-lag):
        sumh += data[:-lag,lag:][i,j]-data[:-lag,:-lag][i,j]
```

But now we note that all our loops are just iterating over a simple index, `[i,j]`, so we can flatten them entirely:

```
sumw = (data[lag:,:-lag] - data[:-lag,:-lag]).sum()
sumh = (data[:-lag,lag:] - data[:-lag,:-lag]).sum()
```

This can be made even faster by spotting that the sum of the difference is the difference of the sums:

```
sumw = data[lag:,:-lag].sum() - data[:-lag,:-lag].sum()
sumh = data[:-lag,lag:].sum() - data[:-lag,:-lag].sum()
```

At this point, you can think about the overall task visually:

[image]

You want `sumw` as the sum over the green outline minus the sum over the red outline, and `sumh` as the sum over the blue outline minus the sum over the red outline.

Here, we can make one of two simplifications:

1. We note that most of the elements in the first sum are being removed from the second sum. In fact, the only elements for which this is not the case are 
   `[:lag]` and `[-lag:]`. So this becomes:

   ```
   sumw = data[-lag:,:-lag].sum() - data[:lag,:-lag].sum()
   sumh = data[:-lag,-lag:].sum() - data[:-lag,:lag].sum()
   ```

   Which will be faster provided that `lag < len(data) / 2`. Here, we are setting `sumw = green - (red + magenta)`, and `sumh = blue - (red + yellow)`
2. We note that the second sum is repeated, so have

   ```
   sum_shared = data[:-lag,:-lag].sum()
   sumw = data[lag:,:-lag].sum() - sum_shared 
   sumh = data[:-lag,lag:].sum() - sum_shared
   ```

Comment: Eric, Thanks! but something is not correct here: I printed sumw, sumh for each of the code fragments above label 0-5 and got values:
0 10512.0 135002.0,
1 10512.0 135002.0,
2 10512.0 135002.0,
3 10720.0 135750.0,
4 10720.0 135750.0,
5 -10720.0 -135750.0

Comment: How are you concluding that those numbers are not correct? And what am I supposed to deduce from those numbers ,given I have no context at all. Does my approach give the same results as your approach?

Comment: So if you look at the break down of the code above there are 6 blocks of code in your transformation of my problem, label them 0-5 and after each block I added "print N, sumw, sumh" where N= 0..5 respectively. Then blocks 0, 1, 2 print the same results, 3, 4 are the same but different from 0, 1, 2, and 5 is the same as 3, 4 but negated. It seems like 3, 4, 5 are summing one or more additional terms. Not sure why 5 is negated. By the way, your break down of the problem is excellent and tutorial, thanks!

Comment: 5 is negated because it is wrong! That one is easy to fix. Can you confirm that `lag` is non-zero and positive?

Comment: I think I see my mistake

Comment: Yes, lag is always 0 < lag < len(data) / 2

Comment: Awesome, those changes now return the same results for all! Now I have to figure out the meaning of [stuff:stuff:stuff] :)

Comment: Updated with an image. `[a:b,c:d]` just takes a rectangular slice of the image from `(a, c) to (b, d)`